# How to fix setState called during build issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I'm trying to open my warning dialog automatically when a user go to details screen but some reason I'm getting setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error in the screen (pic).
I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help on how I should fix this error.

```
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBarWidget(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          showReorder: false,
        ),
        body: BaseView<CardViewModel>(
          onDeactivate: (model) {},
          onDispose: (model) {},
          onModelReady: (model) {
            model.getCard();
          },
          builder: (context, model, child) {
            setState(() {
              isLargeScreen = false;
              if (model.cards.current != true) {
                if (model.cards.alreadyShow == false) {
                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                    staticwarningDialog(context);
                  });
                }
              }
            });
            return _body(model, height, width, context, widget.cardName);
          },
        ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can move your `setState` method to `initState` like this. Remember don't use setState method on build.

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
     (_) {
      setState(() {
        // Your code
      });
    },
   );
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for this but if I move my setState method to initState and outside of the build method then I'm getting an error on my model.cards.current and model.cards.alreadyShow since it saying " Undefined name 'model'. " any idea how I should fix this?.

Comment: I don't know much about your `model`. Since you used model from the `builder` method, you can not access it from initState. Please try to get the model from initState by doing something. I can't help when I don't know how to access your `model` code. Please notice that your question for "How can I get model from initState?" will be the new question and I think you need to start it when you want to ask.

Comment: Make a new stateful widget, pass your model to it as an argument, move everything to it. Next, you can follow what @ToraCode wrote.